# Could not run old java SE apps when installed ME SDK 3.0.5

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

I installed Java ME SDK 3.0.5 to create MIDlets but as soon as it pluged into NetBeans i can't run SE apps that were alright before. For instance i get the error message

`C:\Documents and Settings\user\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache\executor-snippets\run.xml:52: C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Hw2_1\work is not a valid directory
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.setupWorkingDir(Java.java:855)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.setupExecutable(Java.java:825)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:788)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:214)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Java Result: -1`

from an app that worked just fine before. What could have caused that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, a NetBeans update was needed. I am giving the link here in case someone else encounters the same problem and happens to read this.

Java ME SDK Team Blog - [Update Java ME SDK through Update Center](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/update_java_me_sdk_through):

> We found out that after installing Java ME SDK 3.0.5 plug-ins for NB, you can not run Java SE apps any longer. The issue is fixed now, but you need to update it through update center. Here is a step-by-step guide...